# Nginx to serve secure and non secure traffic

Tags: nginx

We have secure and non-secure domains for our website e.g. secure.xyz.com and xyz.com

I used following link to make single server handle both port 80 and 443 traffic.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name secure.xyz.com xyz.com;
....
ssl_certificate secure.xyz.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key secure.xyz.com.key;
...
}
```

Every thing works fine except that $_SERVER's variable 'SERVER_NAME' is set to 'secure.xyz.com'. So that this hostname appears on non-secure page with 'http', e.g., 'http://secure.xyz.com'.

My queries are:

1. Does Nginx always pick the first server from the config ... irrespective of what client has requested? (and passes to proxy (php-fpm)?).
2. We have a lot of rules, so if we create two separate server (as per following), do I need to copy the rules in both places? Is there any maintainable way, like 'include /common_rules.conf'? I tried using 'location' rules (only) in the file, also I tried using 'server' encapsulating location rules however it does not work.

   server {
   listen 443;
   server_name secure.xyz.com;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate secure.xyz.com.crt;
   ...
   include common_rules.conf; ===>???
   }

   server {
   listen 80;
   server_name xyz.com;
   ...
   include common_rules.conf; ===>???
   }

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could also use `'SERVER_PORT'` to determine how your application is being accessed. You can have them in seperate server blocks and  [include](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#include) a common file of rewrites as well. Within such a file, just make sure to include [location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) blocks :)

Comment: OK.. the include rule file work properly with location blocks. Problem I was facing because the *.conf was also getting included at 'http' level which was incorrect.